# Emacs work with archive. What is the best package?

Tags: emacs

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1.

Sometime I need to work with archive (zip, 7z). I do the next action with archives:

1. open archive
2. edit files in archive
3. copy files from/to archive
4. delete files from archive

How I can do this in Emacs? Maybe I need to download some package?

---

*edit*:

> Normally Emacs opens a zip archive and shows its content normally...

No it's not work. Here example.

1. I enter to zip file
2. And try to open (press Enter) file build.gradle
3. Result on screen (No such file or directory)

[image]

Comment: Hi, what did you try ? Normally Emacs opens a zip archive and shows its content normally, as we are used too with Dired.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [emacs.se]

Comment: It's not work in Dired mode. See example below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the issue right there in your screenshot:

> Searching for program: No such file or directory, unzip

You simply do not have an `unzip` executable installed on your computer (or certainly not in any of the <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `exec-path` directories).

Emacs knows how to list the zip file contents without invoking `unzip`, but it can't extract files without that external program.

Comment: Is it possible in Emacs (Windows) to edit file in zip only in Emacs (not in external application)?

Comment: External utilities like un/zip, tar, etc, are mandatory for manipulating archive files. There's simply no good reason for anyone to implement that functionality in elisp when there are perfectly good standard programs which do that job. Emacs does *integrate* with them when they're present, though, so that you can use Emacs to manipulate archives, with Emacs talking to the external program behind the scenes.